# How do I get the date of a file in a directory?

Tags: kotlin

I am new with developing in Kotlin and currently, I am facing an issue.

What I am trying to reach is to print the date, file name, file size and modification date of all files within a directory.

To do so I found out that I can iterate through the files of a directory with the following code.

```
fun getFileDirectoryFiles() {
    File("$fileDirectory").walk().forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

I have figured out that I can get the name(string) and the last modified(long). But I can not find anything about the creation date or file size?

Could someone give me some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun getFileDirectoryFiles(fileDirectory: String) {
    File(fileDirectory)
        .walk()
        .forEach {
            val attributes = Files.readAttributes(it.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes::class.java)

            val name = it.name
            val creationTime = attributes.creationTime()
            val lastModified = attributes.lastModifiedTime()
            val sizeInBytes = attributes.size()
            val sizeInKilobites = sizeInBytes / 1024

            println(
                "name: $name, creationTime: $creationTime, lastModified: $lastModified, sizeInBytes: $sizeInBytes, sizeInKilobites: $sizeInKilobites"
            )
        }
}
```